# Save context for active choice reactive parameters in Jenkins pipelines

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I'm going to improve my parameterized pipelines. I want to save previous selected items in active choice reactive parameters for each value from active choice parameter on which reactive choice parameter depends. I tried to use a *this* variable in Groovy script of active choice reactive parameter:

```
// A - active choice parameter on which reactive choice parameter depends
if (!this.hasProperty('B')) {
    this.B = [:]
}
if (this.B.containsKey(A)) {
    return this.B[A]
} else {
    // save and return some default values
    if (A == 1) {
        this.B[A] = ['val1.1', 'val1.2']
    } else {
        this.B[A] = ['val2.1', 'val2.2']
    }
    return this.B[A]
}
```

Hovewer, *this* of active choice reactive parameter references to new object after changing of active choice parameter.
Does scope of variables of declarative pipelines have any general context for store some values in it during selecting parameters for new build?